# Copy a table and dependencies

Tags: sql-server, copy

I made an error in updating a table and the quickest solution was to replace the table with a backup from previous night. No other changes had been made to the table prior to the backup.

I renamed the existing table that had errors to table_old and used SQL import tool to import the backup copy of table into the correct database. I realize that my dependencies are not present for the copied table.

Q: is is possible to copy the dependencies into the table that I used for the backup? I assume the dependencies would be included if I imported data + Schema?

Regards,

Comment: Are you saying, you want to copy data from a table and all it's dependent tables?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:
Rename the new table to table_backup.  Rename original table to its original name table.  Truncate table table. Insert table Select * from table_backup.  You may need to set identity insert on if you have such a column in the table.